# How to get the indexes of where the values of an array are different in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that looks like (simplified version):

[14 14 14 14 14 13 13 13 13 13 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]

What I need to do is to identify the index where it changes. Like index 5 is 13 and so on. I do not know how to do this. Any kind of help is welcomed!! :)

I've tried it with np.unique, but the output of this sorts the numbers ascending, so I lose where the numbers actually change.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped! I finally got to solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pythonic way, using a list comprehension:

```
arr=[15,14,14,14,14,14,13,13,13,13,13,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3]                                   

[i+1 for i in range(len(arr)-1) if arr[i] != arr[i+1]]                                        
# >>> [1, 6, 11, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare each item in the array with the next item using `a[1:]!=a[:-1]` (for some 1d array `a`). You can then convert this array of booleans to indices by using `np.where`. Because of the slicing, you need to add one to this.

```
# added a 4 to the end of the array to have an extra place where the number changes
a=np.array([14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,4])
changes = np.where(a[1:]!=a[:-1])[0]+1
print('change indices:',changes)
print('before each change:',a[changes-1])
print('after each change:',a[changes])
```

This outputs:

```
change indices: [ 5 10 19]
before each change: [14 13  2]
after each change: [13  2  4]
```

Comment: Big thanks!! This worked!! It's similar to another posted and both worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is fastest way possible to find the unique number index change.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([14, 14, 14, 13, 20, 20, 20, 2, 2, 2])

np.unique(arr, return_index=True)
```

#### Output

```
(array([ 2, 13, 14, 20]), array([7, 3, 0, 4]))
```

Comment: np.unique shows the values sorted, so it does not solve what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

**Check out this code :**

```
arr = [14,14,14,14,14,13,13,13,13,13,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
k = arr[0]
for i, j in enumerate(arr):
    if k != j:
        print(i) 
    k = arr[i]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
5
10
```

Answer (score -1):

It very simple use a loop

```
all_indexes = []
lisst = [14,14, 14, 14, 14, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 2, 2 ,2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
for i in range(len(lisst)-1):
    if lisst[i] != lisst[i+1]:
        all_indexes.append(i+1)
        
        
print(all_indexes)
```